# How do I copy first 3 lines and last 2 lines of a file, and create new file

Tags: linux, sh

So I've a question how do I copy first 3 lines and last 2 files in linux and put them into new file

So I have file: **moja.txt** and content in this file is

```
(Name)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and I'd like to make new file kombinacija.txt and content in this file would be:

```
(Name)
1
2
9
10
```

Comment: What would you like to do with a file that is only 4 lines long?  Should the output be the same as the input, or should the 3rd line be duplicated?  What about files that are only 1 line?  Or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
head -n 3 moja.txt > kombinacija.txt &&
  tail -n -2 moja.txt >> kombinacija.txt
```